How to prevent background page resizing when using The49.Maui.BottomSheet in full-screen mode?
I am using The49.Maui.BottomSheet to display sheets in my app. I created a BaseSheet.cs and its corresponding XAML file, and all my sheets inherit from this base class.
BaseSheet itself inherits from BottomSheet.
One of my sheets displays a list of items inside a grid. When the list is very large, the sheet opens to full screen, and I can scroll through the rest of the items.
However, when this happens, the background page seems to shrink and resize, and only returns to its normal size after closing the sheet.
I would like to prevent this effect, so that the background page stays fixed. What can I do to achieve this?
